# How to call an element using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, odoo

any idea how can I call this element `<p class="one">Show me</p>` in ajax? I am using `ajax.jsonRpc()` so that I can access to the web controller.

In jQuery:

`$("p.one").addClass("show");`

Any idea on how to do it here using ajax?

```
 var ajax = require('web.ajax');


 ajax.jsonRpc('/custom/createaccount', 'call', {
    'db_name': db_name,
    'contact_name': contact_name,
    'email_from': email_from,
},{ 'async': false }).then(function(){
    console.log('created user account')
});
```

Comment: you mean "using" ajax - did you try examples on jQuery docs? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ It's  $.ajax({ ... not ajax. + use dataType:"json" ...

Comment: hello @trainoasis, I am using odoo.

Comment: Oh, I'd go directly to their support forums for  thart were I you, sry